# IONIC | FAILURE: Build failed with an exception

Tags: java, android, cordova, ionic-framework

Can you please help me I already googled the problem and ran the tips. But all that didn't work out.
Here are the pictures

[image: Error Image 1]

[image: Error Image 2]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although you set the maximum heap size to 512MB, it is still not enough for starting the VM. In the error message you can see: `Could not reserve enough space for 2097152KB object heap`.

2097152KB are over 2GB, so you need at least `-Xmx2G` or more. Keep in mind that you also need sufficent RAM installed.